# Save way to create a Firestore document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I made a game with JavaScript in which the user takes a specific amount of time to complete it. Then I want to create a document in a collection named scores on Firestone with that time. My problem is that the user can create an infinite amount of documents with a random time by simply copy & pasting the code and entering their own values. Is there a way that the user can only create once a document with the correct time at the end of the game? Here is the code that I used:

```
db.collection('score').add({
    time: 122,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two requirements I think:

1. The user should only be able to create one document.
2. The time in the document must be the current time at the end of the game.

---

#### Allow only one document per user

The first one is easiest to do by using Firebase Authentication to sign the user in, so that they have an identity. If you don't want the user to enter any credentials, you can sign them in [using anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth).

No matter how you sign them in, this gives them a unique UID (user identifier), which you can then use as the document ID:

```
let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
db.collection('score').doc(uid).set({
    time: 122,
});
```

So instead of calling `add()` (which generates a new document each time you call it), we create a document with the user's UID as its name. That way the user will always be writing to the same document.

You can then enforce that the user can only write their own document with Firebase's server-side security rules. See for an example of this, the documentation on [content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

---

#### Ensure the time can't be spoofed

To prevent the user from writing just any value they wish into the database, we can [use Firestore's built-in `FieldValue.serverTimestamp` marker value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp). When you use this in your code, the Firestore server automatically writes in the current value from the server:

```
let uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
db.collection('score').doc(uid).set({
    time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});
```

Here too, you can then use Firebase's server-side security rules to ensure that a malicious user can't pass their own value. To do that, compare the value that is being written (`request.data.time`) with the [built-in variable for the current time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#time) (`request.time`).

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my Problem:)